# Notice: undefined variable: con and Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Tags: php, mysql

im currently have 2 problems. The `undefined variable` and `mysqli_real_escape_string`

These are the `notice` and `warning`:

Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\ngab\login.php on line 14

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ngab\login.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\ngab\login.php on line 16

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ngab\login.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\ngab\login.php on line 18

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ngab\login.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\ngab\login.php on line 21

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ngab\login.php on line 21

These are my codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
     <?php
     require('db.php');
     session_start();
     if (isset($_POST['username'])){
        $user_ID = stripslashes($_REQUEST['user_ID']);
         $user_ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$user_ID);
         $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']);
         $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);
$password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `teacher_table` WHERE user_ID='$user_ID' 
    and username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($rows==1){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header("Location: home.php");
     }else{
echo "<div class='form'>
   <h3>User ID/username/password is incorrect.</h3>
    <br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
}
}else{
   ?>
     <div class="form">
   <h1>Log In</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" name="login">
   <input type="text" name="user_ID" placeholder="User ID" required />
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
     </form>
    <p>Not registered yet? <a href='registration.php'>Register Here</a></p>
     </div>
     <?php } ?>
     </body>
     </html>
```

And this is the `db.php` is:

```
    <?php
     $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
     if(!$connect)
     {
       echo "Error".mysql_error();
        }
       $db=mysql_select_db("attendance_db");
       if(!$db)
        {
           echo "Error".mysql_error();
           }
          ?>
```

Thanks. I would like to know whats wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: your code is failing on way too many levels.

Comment: Want someone to repeat you the error message once more?

Comment: You have *not defined* $con - hence "undefined variable".

Comment: stick with one api (mysqli_) and the same variable for the connection and don't mix different apis, `mysql_` and `mysqli_` do not intermix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line looks like copied from some code some were else
`$user_ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$user_ID);` `$con` is your database connection and right now `$con` is not defined its giving a `NULL` and `mysqli` doesnt understand.

You are also using `mysql_connect` and that is not correct. You cannot use `mysqli`and `mysql` they are 2 different things. I would learn `mysqli` over `mysql` because `mysql` will be no longer used soon.
`Mysqli_connect();`

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
if($mysqli->connect_error) die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
//this will connect to database with mysqli if not it will stop and post error
```

Your code `$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);` has too many problems between `mysql` and `mysqli`

Please Look Here And Choose 1, but **do not intermix** different MySQL APIs.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php (preferred)

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php (deprecated and deleted as of PHP 7)